Can I change a SharePoint field type?
I have uploaded Access tables to a SharePoint site.  I had all my relationships properly made but somehow one of my tables has a field that should have turned into a lookup type in SharePoint and it did not.  Is there a way to change the SharePoint list field from a number field to a lookup type?
This field is not an ID field but it is part of a 1 to many join in Access front end.
I looked at the field in SharePoint and I don't see a way to change the field from a number type to a lookup type.

sorry, you can't change the field type to Lookup from other types. And vice versa as well: you can't change from Lookup to anything.
(slightly related, that the following types are interchangeable): single line of text, multiple lines of text, choice, number, currency and date+time.

What is the best way to resolve my issue?  Do I make another Lookup field and then transfer the data?

if your data let this approach (not too many records or too many fields, without triggered flows), then yes, I would make a new lookup field as well.
